# C# GetAttribute does not work

Tags: c#, html

I have this page HTML: http://wotlk.openwow.com/spell=1

I open this page in my application using this call:

```
webBrowser.Navigate()
```

I am interested in acquiring a variable the contents of the `style` attribute of the `ins` tag, and I used this syntax.

```
String tmp = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("ins")[0].GetAttribute ("style");
```

After the execution of the program content of `tmp` is "System .__ ComObjec"

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `.ToString()` after `.GetAttribute`

Comment: @simone989 are you sure the <ins> exists on the page?

Comment: Yes, However I solved saved all the content of the tag <HTML> into a string, and from there I extract what I needed with the substring